# Guardar resultado de Array en Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, foreach

con ayuda he utilizado el siguiente codigo que me permite ingresar datos desde un input y que el mismo sea separado en 3 diferentes valores que necesito, que son valor, codigo y serial

```
<?php
$datos = "3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555";
// divides por espacios y cada 7 elementos, los elementos de cada fila
$temp = array_chunk(explode(' ', $datos), 7);
$ar = array();

foreach($temp as $key => $v) {
    // optienes el 1º elemento valor
    $ar[$key]['valor'] = array_shift($v);
    // optienes el ultimo elemento, serial
    $ar[$key]['serial'] = array_pop($v);
    // lo que queda es el codigo, lo unes con espacios
    $ar[$key]['codigo'] = implode(' ', $v);
}


print_r($ar); // esto me da como resultado el Array
```

En el ejemplo ofrecido muy gentilmente por @Xerif me he encontrado ahora un nuevo reto y es que debo generar el INSERT de estos datos generados en una base de datos usando MySQLi la tabla se llama `tarjetas` con la siguiente estructura: `id, valor, codigo, serial` el id es autoincrement he intentado hacerlo de varias formas pense que yo solo lo lograria pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, pueden por favor brindarme orientacion de como debo hacerlo..?

ya se que `$ar[0][valor]` me daria el valor del primer array pero no logro visualizar como debo hacer el INSERT en mi Base de datos cuando son ejemplo 50 valores mas sus respectivos 50 codigos y 50 seriales..!

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, valor, codigo, serial)
VALUES null, '$valor', '$codigo', '$serial'";
```

Implementando la sugerencia he hecho lo siguiente:

```
 function entregar_pedido(){
    global $db;

    $id_pedido = ($_GET['id']);
    $user = ($_GET['user']);
    $lote_pedido = $_REQUEST['lote'];

    $datos = "3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555";
// divides por espacios y cada 7 elementos, los elementos de cada fila
$temp = array_chunk(explode(' ', $datos), 7);
$ar = array();

foreach($temp as $key => $v) {
    // optienes el 1º elemento monto
    $ar[$key]['monto'] = array_shift($v);
    // optienes el ultimo elemento, serial
    $ar[$key]['serial'] = array_pop($v);
    // lo que queda es el codigo, lo unes con espacios
    $ar[$key]['codigo'] = implode(' ', $v);

    $monto =   $ar[$key]['monto'];
    $codigo =  $ar[$key]['codigo'];
    $serial =  $ar[$key]['serial'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, monto, codigo, serial, usuario, id_pedido)
        VALUES(null, '$monto', ' $codigo', '$serial', '$user', '$id_pedido')";    

}
mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or mysqli_error($db);

if (mysqli_query($db, $sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}

}
```

Pero solo me guarda el primer dato 3 veces, algo asi

```
3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555
3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555
3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555
```

no logro hacer que guarde completo los datos requeridos.

Posiblemente no es la mejor practica pero logre solucionar efectuando una modificacion en la estructura de mi base de datos colocando una key unica en la columna serial y he dejado el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
function entregar_pedido(){
    global $db;

    $id_pedido = ($_GET['id']);
    $user = ($_GET['user']);
    $lote_pedido = $_REQUEST['lote'];

    $datos = "1 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111122222 2 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 22222233333 3 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333 333344444 4 4444 4444 4444 4444 4444 4444555555";
// divides por espacios y cada 7 elementos, los elementos de cada fila
$temp = array_chunk(explode(' ', $datos), 7);
$ar = array();

foreach($temp as $key => $v) {
    // optienes el 1º elemento monto
    $ar[$key]['monto'] = array_shift($v);
    // optienes el ultimo elemento, serial
    $ar[$key]['serial'] = array_pop($v);
    // lo que queda es el codigo, lo unes con espacios
    $ar[$key]['codigo'] = implode(' ', $v);

    $monto =   $ar[$key]['monto'];
    $codigo =  $ar[$key]['codigo'];
    $serial =  $ar[$key]['serial'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, monto, codigo, serial, usuario, id_pedido)
        VALUES(null, '$monto', ' $codigo', '$serial', '$user', '$id_pedido')";   

        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or mysqli_error($db);

}


if (mysqli_query($db, $sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}



    $_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  = "Se ha registrado un nuevo usuario de manera Exitosa.<br>";

    echo $user;
    echo $lote_pedido;



}
```

Lógicamente quedo atento a mejoras que le pueda hacer a mi codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para una consulta insert de varios valores, puedes crearla directamente añadiendo cada registro separado por comas, de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, valor, codigo, serial)
VALUES (null, '$valor1', '$codigo1', '$serial1') ,
       (null, '$valor2', '$codigo2', '$serial2'),
       (null, '$valor3', '$codigo3', '$serial3'),
       (null, '$valor4', '$codigo4', '$serial4'),
       (null, '$valor5', '$codigo5', '$serial5'),
";
```

Por tanto, podrias construir la instruccion con un bucle, algo asi:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, valor, codigo, serial) VALUES ";

foreach($registros as $registro) {
   $sql.= "(null, '".$registro['valor']."', '".$registro['codigo']." ', '".$registro['serial']."')";
};

$sql.=";";
```

Comment: Acabo de modificar el codigo pero aun no funciona, acabo de editar mi consulta para ver que exactamente estoy haciedo mal.

Comment: Hay que ajustar un poco el código. Date cuenta que cada línea debe ir entre paréntesis y acabar con una coma, excepto el último que cierra la instrucción y sería con ;

Comment: sigo intentando, acabo de editar mi consulta con los datos de como lo llevo en este momento.

Comment: de manera temporal logre hacer funcionar mi codigo, no estoy muy contento con la solucion que implemente, sigo igual intentando una mejor manera de hacerlo..!