# Como se pueden insertar diferentes fechas desde un bucle incremental desde c# a MySql?

Tags: c#

Lo que quiero lograr es insertar varias fechas por mes incrementalmente con un bucle e insertarlas en una tabla de MySql.

Ya tengo realizado un bucle que genera mas de un registro, pero no toma diferentes fechas del bucle que realicé para las fechas, solo me toma una sola que es la que ingreso. Si me lo hace en un `listbox` o `listview`, también en `label` pero colocando mas de uno dejo los codigos y imagenes.

Este código es mi bóton ingresar:

```
int valor = txtplazo.SelectedIndex;
DateTime date1 = txtfcaducidad.Value;
Fechas Fechas = new Fechas();
Fechas.nomcompromiso = txtnomcompr.Text;
Fechas.plazo = txtplazo.Text;
Fechas.fdepago = txtfdeplazo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
{
    Fechas.fcaducidad = date1.AddMonths(i).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}

Fechas.valordecuota = txtvalorcuota.Text;
Fechas.pago = txtpago.Text;
Fechas.formadepago = txtformapago.Text;
int resultado = DALFechas.Agregar(Fechas);
```

Aquí mi código donde hace el `insert` con el bucle para ingresar mas de un registro:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    using (MySqlConnection Conn = BDcomun.ObtnerCOnexion())
    {
        MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Insert Into compromisos (nomcompromiso, tipodeplazo, fdepago, fcaducidad, valordecuota, pago, formadepago) values ('{0}', '{1}', NULL, @fdecaducidad, '{4}', NULL, NULL)",
                    pfechas.nomcompromiso, pfechas.plazo, pfechas.fdepago, pfechas.fcaducidad, pfechas.valordecuota, pfechas.pago, pfechas.formadepago), Conn);

        Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdecaducidad", pfechas.fcaducidad);
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Comando);
                    retorno = Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Conn.Close();

    }
}
```

[image: Con el boton 5 donde tengo el bucle las muestro atraves de varios label en este caso me gustaria hacer lo mismo pero que se ingresen en MySql:]

[image: Aca como se puede ver registre un compromiso pero sale con la misma fecha la que ingrese siendo que estoy utilizando el bucle, pero este al parecer no funciona para Mysql:]

Comment: respondi algo parecido hace poco, pero sobre php. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198374/guardar-resultado-de-array-en-mysql/198377#198377. La idea es crear un `values` por cada linea que necesites

Comment: Hmm, no se entiende muy bien la pregunta la verdad. Lo primero, tienes un bucle sin sentido en tu botón ingresar, ya que metes dos veces en `fcaducidad` un valor, con lo que el anterior se elimina. En cuanto a como resolverlo, porque en el bucle de inserción no vas añadiendo un mes a la fecha? `pfechas.fcaducidad=nuevafecha`. Por último,  nunca entederé por que manejais las fechas como string, complica siempre todo.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aca hay un importante error de concepto. Las variables solo tienen un valor, y es el ultimo ingresado. Acuerdo con todo lo que dice @Pikoh.

Answer (score 0):

Pude realizarlo atraves de una consulta a MySql, la idea es hacer un tabla aparte llamada enteros en la misma base de datos insertar un registro de numeros enteros del 0 al 9, con between se le puede dar la cantidad de registros en este caso puse de 0 a 9 serian 10 registros con esto no es necesario hacer un bucle en este caso.

Esto lo que haria insertar varios registros y en la fecha la cual selecionaste ir colocandola por mes de manera incremental, esto se puede modificar, si lo quieres anual seria year o por dia, day, el select despues de insert into actua como el value en este caso.

```
 "INSERT INTO compromisoss (nomcompromisos, tipodeplazo, fdepago, fcaducidad, valordecuota, pago, formadepago) 
                                                                                SELECT '{0}', '{1}', NULL, ADDDATE('{3}', INTERVAL SomeNumber month), '{4}', null, null                                                                               FROM (SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100+d.i*1000 AS SomeNumber FROM enteros a, enteros b, enteros c, enteros d) Sub1 WHERE SomeNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 9"
```